# What is the correct XPath for an xml with a different xml declaration?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to set up an XPath query for the following xml:

```
<Assembly xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns="Assembly">
  <Parts>
    <Part>
      <PartName>Example</PartName>
    </Part>
  </Parts>
<Assembly>
```

I need the PartName element and I have not been able to reference it correctly since the xml declaration is a node and not the usual

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Can someone help me structure my XPath?

Comment: Be careful of any declared namespaces. I can see an xmlns="..." in your node. This can confuse XML Parsers if you don't specify them correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML + XPATH: Any way to work with a default Namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439739/xml-xpath-any-way-to-work-with-a-default-namespace)

Comment: I do have a namespace but cannot name it here.

Comment: Is the namespace URI a secret? Why not make one up just for this question? And I don't understand what you mean by "the xml declaration is a node".

Comment: I added Assembly as an example for the URI and I was just thinking, would the URI be a problem since it is just a "word"?  And I just meant that the xml declaration is a root node and there is no <?xml...?> declaration.

Comment: @sange: Not a problem, but do note that relative URIs have been deprecated http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xppa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I had to set my namespace manager in my C# program that used the XPath:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(Document.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("sc", "Assembly");
```

and the XPath was `//sc:Parts/sc:Part/sc:PartName`

Comment: +1 for answering your own question. FYI - the XML declaration is optional (though recommended). It serves as a clue to XML parsers, but does not affect the parsed infoset. So, it will not affect the XPath if it is in the document or not.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring/registering the namespace and using the namespace prefix in your XPath is definitely preferred.

However, if you want an XPath that will work without registering the namespaces, you can use either of the following XPath statements:

```
/*[local-name()='Assembly' and namespace-uri()='Assembly']
  /*[local-name()='Parts' and namespace-uri()='Assembly']
    /*[local-name()='Part' and namespace-uri()='Assembly']
      /*[local-name()='PartName' and namespace-uri()='Assembly']
```

This one is shorter, but less "safe" as it only matches against the element names and does not use the namespace as criteria.

```
/*[local-name()='Assembly']
  /*[local-name()='Parts']
    /*[local-name()='Part']
      /*[local-name()='PartName']
```

They are long and ugly, but will work.

Answer (score 1):

//Assembly/Parts/Part/PartName

Comment: Not correct. This selects elements with null or empty namespace URI.