# xPath expression doesn't result expected value

Tags: xml, xpath, soap

When I try to execute this xPath expression

```
//s:Envelope/s:Body/get_serviceDetail/serviceKey/text()
```

against this XML document

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <get_serviceDetail generic="1.0" xmlns="urn:uddi-org:api">
      <serviceKey>66</serviceKey>
    </get_serviceDetail>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I get always No Match, and I can't see why

Anyone can hel me? I'm sure it has to be something quite evident that I'm missing.

Comment: you sould register namespace before using xpath by method of your library or use trick `//s:Envelope/s:Body/*[name() = "get_serviceDetail"]/*[name()="serviceKey"]/text()`

Comment: Ok, that worked like a charm, if you want to post it like an answer I'll gladly accept it

Comment: Glad that could help. But if you use correct way of working with namespace it will be better

Comment: I'm using it just to redirect to the correct response on SOAP UI depending on request. It's just for testing purposes on development environment, so I think that your trick will be perfectly fit for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML + XPATH: Any way to work with a default Namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439739/xml-xpath-any-way-to-work-with-a-default-namespace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register namespace before using xpath by method of your library (it's more correct) or use trick

```
//s:Envelope/s:Body/*[name() = "get_serviceDetail"]/*[name()="serviceKey"]/text()
```